# Null csv output

Tags: powershell

I have this old code that works for the last months. Someone here helped me for this. I have run the code with a small dataset and getting the output well. However, last time i run this to a whole AD, everything is okay and I am getting a csv output data.

I am now getting this error and I am not getting any output at the end, Thank you so much for the future help.

ERROR:
Get-ADGroup: Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot create object of type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup". The adapter cannot set the value of property "Name".

So The code is getting all the groups in AD and getting specific attributes from there.

Code:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $false,HelpMessage = "Specify a output file name to be used for OneAbbotData.")]
    [string]
    $destinationPath = $null
)
write-host "******************************************************************" -ForegroundColor Green
write-host "*                  Group Data Processing                         *" -ForegroundColor Green
write-host "******************************************************************" -ForegroundColor Green  
#Saving all of the group names to the $groupUsersList variable
$groupUsersList = [system.collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::new()
$groupUsersList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | select Name
# $groupUsersList = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\dd\Desktop\Desktop removed\group321.txt"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
#Declare storage for the table 
$tableStorage = [system.collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::new()
foreach($group in $groupUsersList)
{
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($group))
    {
        continue
    }
#Specift the needed attributes to get
    try
    {
        $hash = @{
            Identity = $group
            Properties = @(
                'Name','GroupCategory'
                'extensionAttribute12','info'
                'LabsInCloud','Created', 'LabsBusinessOwner', 
                'Description'
            )
        }

        $adGroup = Get-ADGroup @hash
   }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_
        continue
    }
#Using Try catch to catch the error if the attribute is empty and unable to split or modify the word 
    try
    {
        $businessOwner = $adGroup.LabsBusinessOwner.Split("=")[1].Split(",")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        'Cant split this: {0}' -f $adGroup.AbbottLabsBusinessOwner
        $businessOwner = $adGroup.LabsBusinessOwner
    }
    
    try
    {
        $info = $adGroup.info.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        'Cant split this: {0}' -f $adGroup.info 
        $info = $adGroup.info
    }

    try
    {
        $owner = $adGroup.extensionAttribute12.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        'Cant split this: {0}' -f $adGroup.extensionAttribute12
        $owner = $adGroup.extensionAttribute12
    }

#Adding the attributes to the variable table storage that we created 
    $tableStorage.Add(
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $adGroup.Name
            GroupCategory = $adGroup.GroupCategory
            Owner = $owner
            OwnerinfoID = $info 
            InCloud =  $adGroup.LabsInCloud
            Created =  $adGroup.Created
            Owner2 = $BusinessOwner
            Description =  $adGroup.Description
            Owner3 =  $adGroup.info   
            atttrib12 =  $adGroup.extensionAttribute12
    })


}

#Exporting the table if its not empty
if($tableStorage)
{
    $tableStorage | Export-Csv -Path $destinationPath -NoTypeInformation -Force
    write-host "CSV Exported successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: Try removing `| select Name` from `Get-ADGroup -Filter *| select Name`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Trying it right now. This will run in a few hours since it's huge. Thank you and I will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

You request AD Groups and then you request each AD group for additional properties. This is clearly not the way to go. You have to request all the properties in the first request. So yes for the moment your script take hours but this kind of script should never run in more than one hour even on very big directories.
All the other stuff is not really wrong but not very clean.

Try this version if you want. Shorter, cleaner, faster.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $false, HelpMessage = "Specify a output file name to be used for OneAbbotData.")]
    [string]
    $Path = $null
)

Get-ADGroup -Filter * -ResultPageSize 1000 -Properties 'Name','GroupCategory','extensionAttribute12','info', 'Description', 'Created', 'LabsInCloud', 'LabsBusinessOwner' |
ForEach-Object {

    $businessOwner = $_.LabsBusinessOwner
    $info = $_.info
    $owner = $_.extensionAttribute12
    
    try
    {
        $businessOwner = $_.LabsBusinessOwner.Split("=")[1].Split(",")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host $('Cant split LabsBusinessOwner: {0}' -f $_.LabsBusinessOwner)
    }
    
    try
    {
        $info = $_.info.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host $('Cant split info: {0}' -f $_.info) 
    }

    try
    {
        $owner = $_.extensionAttribute12.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host $('Cant split extensionAttribute12: {0}' -f $_.extensionAttribute12)
    }

    $_ | Select-Object Name, GroupCategory, Created, Description,
        @{l='Owner';e = { $owner }},
        @{l='Owner2'; e= { $businessOwner }},
        @{l='OwnerInfoID'; e = { $info }},
        @{l='attrib12'; e= { $_.extensionAttribute12 }}
} `
| Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Your directory has some custom attributes 'LabsInCloud', 'LabsBusinessOwner' and I don't know the various `Split()` parts so I globally left them as is.